# reRender attribute within component

Tags: visualforce-component, rerender

I have a problem with the rerender attribute not working when i try to use it within a visualforce component. Here is my code:

My component:

```
<apex:component controller="zTestController" id="myComponent">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:inputText value="{!text}" id="myText"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!someAction}" reRender="{!$Component.myComponent}" value="testButton"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

My page:

```
<apex:page >
  <c:zTestComponent />
</apex:page>
```

The controller class:

```
public class zTestController {
  public String text {get; set {
    text = (value!=null?value:'') + 'X';
  }}

  public void someAction() {
  }
}
```

When i click on the button, nothing happens. 
If i remove the rerender attribute, the button works.
If i don't use a component and copy the content to the page, the button works.

I did not find any reported bugs about this, so am i doning wrong? any Ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<apex:component controller="zTestController">
 <apex:form >
   <apex:outputPanel id="myComponent">
     <apex:inputText value="{!text}" id="myText"/>
 </apex:outputPanel>
<apex:commandButton action="{!someAction}" reRender="myComponent" value="testButton"/>
```

> **I always use outputPanel whenever i reRender and also i use pagereference method and return null**

```
public class zTestController {
  public String text {get; set {
   text = (value!=null?value:'') + 'X';
 }}

    public pagereference someAction() {
      return null;
   }
}
```